# Losing internet access when creating ethernet bridge for OpenVPN

Tags: arch-linux, openvpn

I'm trying to set up an ethernet bridge with OpenVPN. I create my bridge using this script I got from the setup guide on openvpn.org, modified slightly to work on Arch Linux.

```
# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth="eth0"
eth_ip="192.168.1.202"
eth_netmask="255.255.255.0"
eth_broadcast="192.168.1.255"

for t in $tap; do
    openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

brctl addbr $br
#brctl addif $br $eth

for t in $tap; do
    brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
    ip link set dev $t promisc on
done

ip link set dev $eth promisc on

#ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast
```

This works except the server loses its internet connection immediately after running the script until I reboot. I am still able to connect on the client, and routing all data through the vpn with `push "redirect-gateway def1"` seems to work - if I try to ping google.com on the client, I get a message from the server saying that it can't be reached. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I removed the bridge to eth0 as suggested in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/624743/setting-up-bridged-openvpn-server-with-single-public-ip-nic?rq=1). I also commented out `ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast`. Everything now seems to work, except for the fact that I can't ping the client from the server.

When I do a traceroute to google.com, it goes through 192.168.1.109 before going through my router. This address is in my vpn routing tables, so does this mean the traffic is going through the VPN? Another problem could be that the client I have been testing with is on the same local network as the server. Could this be causing problems? With an ethernet bridge, are computers on the local network still able to access clients even if they are not connected to the network? I'll try testing it from another network and update this with my findings.

EDIT 2:

Here's what the routing tables look like on the server:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.2     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.1.109   127.0.0.1       255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 lo
```

Comment: Maybe it is too late, but did you solve the problem, if yes, may be I can help, because I had exactly the same problem before.

Answer (score 4):

When you do bridging with OpenVPN, you'll junction your existing `eth0` and `tap0` into a bridge `br0`.  This is the right thing to do if you want OpenVPN clients to be part of the same network `eth0` is in and allow broadcast traffic to traverse.

When the `eth0` and `tap0` are in a bridge, they are now like ports on a switch, their individual IPs don't matter anymore.  You lose internet connection because `br0` has no IP now.

`br0` is now your NIC and it now needs an IP, either through DHCP or manually assigned.  Try `dhclient -v br0`.

If you don't have a DHCP server running you need to set one up, just for `br0` (it's possible to tell `isc-dhcp-server` to only give out IPs on interface `br0` and not your `eth0`).

Comment: What if I assigned an IP to `br0` with `ifconfig` and the machine is still unreachable?