# Machine loses internet connection after Ethernet Bridge

Tags: vpn, ethernet, openvpn, bridge

I'm basically facing the same issue [described here](https://superuser.com/questions/694661/losing-internet-access-when-creating-ethernet-bridge-for-openvpn) except that I (indeed) assigned an IP to the new bridge interface `br0`.

[(This is a related question)](https://serverfault.com/questions/986542/host-unreachable-if-eth0-has-no-ipv4-in-ethernet-bridge)

What I'm trying to build is a "Data Link VPN".

Therefore, I followed the steps mentioned [in OpenVPNs' official article.](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/ethernet-bridging/)

I modified the script a little (added some lines at the very bottom) to set the required firewall rules and bring the interfaces up.

This is how the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

####################################
# Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux
# Requires: bridge-utils
####################################

# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth="eth0"
eth_ip="192.168.178.20"
eth_netmask="255.255.255.0"
eth_broadcast="192.168.178.255"

for t in $tap; do
  openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

brctl addbr $br
brctl addif $br $eth

for t in $tap; do
  brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
  ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
done

ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast

for t in $tap; do
  iptables -A INPUT -i $t -j ACCEPT
done
iptables -A INPUT -i $br -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $br -j ACCEPT

ifconfig $br up
for t in $tap; do
  ifconfig $t up
done
route add default gw 192.168.178.1

ip addr
ip route
```

Additionally, see the output of `ip addr` and `ip route` below (before and after the script):

*Before:*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:b9:a0:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.20/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd00::6523:63a5:7749:c7a/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7131sec preferred_lft 3531sec
    inet6 fe80::e750:eb6e:6c80:f71c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:ec:f5:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

default via 192.168.178.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.178.20 metric 202 
192.168.178.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.178.20 metric 202
```

*After:*

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:b9:a0:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fd00::6523:63a5:7749:c7a/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6718sec preferred_lft 3118sec
    inet6 fe80::e750:eb6e:6c80:f71c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:ec:f5:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state DOWN group default qlen 100
    link/ether be:71:41:11:89:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:b9:a0:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.20/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:feb9:a00f/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


default via 192.168.178.1 dev br0 
192.168.178.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.20
```

As you can see, `eth0` is the physical interface (LAN).

After running the script, the machine is not reachable anymore from anywhere (it should be accessible on the local LAN via SSH, I cannot ping the machine either).

I use dhcpcd with the following configuration:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.178.20/24
static routers=192.168.178.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.178.1 8.8.8.8
```

so `eth0` is assigned a static IP.

---

After following the steps as mentioned by @TomYan below, I don't start dhcpcd for the new bridge interface though. Instead, I assign the IP from the physical interface and specify the default gateway:

```
ip l set eth0 down
ip a flush eth0

ip l add name bridge0 type bridge

# Swap Ethernet addresses at this point
read eth_mac </sys/class/net/eth0/address
read br_mac </sys/class/net/bridge0/address

ip l set eth0 address $br_mac
ip l set bridge0 address $eth_mac
ip l set eth0 master bridge0

ip l set eth0 promisc on
ip l set bridge0 promisc on

# Set IP address of bridge interface
#ip addr add 192.168.178.20 dev bridge0
ifconfig bridge0 192.168.178.20 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.178.255
route add default gw 192.168.178.1 bridge0

ip l set dev bridge0 up

# Configure the bridge
ip l set dev eth0 up
```

This is the output of `ip a show dev eth0/bridge0` and `ip r show` after executing those commands:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bridge0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a2:f1:00:1c:aa:c2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:b9:a0:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.20/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global bridge0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:feb9:a00f/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

default via 192.168.178.1 dev bridge0 
192.168.178.0/24 dev bridge0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.178.20
```

What's missing? I'm really lost and very glad for any sort of hint.

Comment: Not reachable from where? The Internet?

Comment: From within the private network. I usually access the machine via SSH at 192.168.178.20 @TomYan

Comment: I don't think you are doing it the right way anyway. The result looks pretty broken. You should simply stop the DHCP client, bring down and flush eth0 first and then create the bridge and make eth0 its slave, and then restart the DHCP client on the bridge.

Comment: I would really do it with a network manager or at least `ip` instead (and use a different MAC for the bridge).

Comment: Would you be so kind and provide all that in an answer? That'd be really helpful. @TomYan

Comment: `br0` is supposed to have the same MAC and IP as `eth0`. It is supposed to act like my normal Ethernet interface with the same properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should stop using a script and do it step by step first. To be honest, I don't even see why you would want to set up the bridge with a script, instead of a network manager like systemd-networkd. But if you insist, you can set it all up with iproute2.

Assuming the NIC has already been configured (**for example**, by dhcpcd started **via systemd**), you want to stop **whatever manages it** and "reset" (bring it down and flush the IP addresses) it first:

```
[tom@archlinux ~]$ ip a show dev enp3s0
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:22:0b:29:e6:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.111/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 86381sec preferred_lft 75581sec
    inet6 fe80::736a:adc3:745b:b48d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo systemctl stop dhcpcd@enp3s0
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo ip l set enp3s0 down
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo ip a flush enp3s0
[tom@archlinux ~]$ ip a show dev enp3s0
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:22:0b:29:e6:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Then you can start creating the bridge and make the NIC its slave:

```
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo ip l add name bridge0 type bridge
[tom@archlinux ~]$ ip a show dev bridge0
3: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:f0:20:42:64:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo ip l set enp3s0 address ba:f0:20:42:64:5f
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo ip l set bridge0 address ac:22:0b:29:e6:0c
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo ip l set enp3s0 master bridge0
```

As you can see, I simply "swap" their MAC addresses.

After bring up the NIC, you can configure the bridge just as how you configured the NIC before:

```
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo ip l set enp3s0 up
[tom@archlinux ~]$ sudo systemctl start dhcpcd@bridge0
[tom@archlinux ~]$ ip a show dev enp3s0
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master bridge0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:f0:20:42:64:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[tom@archlinux ~]$ ip a show dev bridge0
3: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:22:0b:29:e6:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.111/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute bridge0
       valid_lft 86392sec preferred_lft 75592sec
    inet6 fe80::736a:adc3:745b:b48d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

You only need to change firewall rules if you actually have enabled a firewall. Even in that case, whether you actually need to make any changes really depends on how it has been configured. It would be silly to just add random rules from the Internet that you don't even know what it does. Also you might be using nftables instead iptables.

---

You don't necessarily need to create tap(s) manually either, as OpenVPN can create it on-demand. You can make it create tap of specific name with the following in your client and server conf:

```
dev whatever
dev-type tap
```

You may want to add `persist-tun` as well. See the manual for details.

---

I am not sure if you actually need to turn [promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) on for the bridge and/or the NIC. If you want to check if it helps for any case, you can run:

```
# ip l set $name promisc on|off
```

I don't think you will need it for the tap(s) in any case though.

Comment: Same input, same output, the machine's still not reachable at all. I tried setting promiscuous mode on for both `eth0` and the bridge.

Comment: @user0800 So how did you configure eth0/bridge0 before/after the steps anyway? (Please don't just copy and paste the dhcpcd start/stop command and expect it to work when you aren't or don't know if you are even using dhcpcd via systemd btw.) You can further clarify and add updates by editing you question.

Comment: @user0800 Also, can you reach your router (default gateway) and/or the Internet though?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Do you mean reach the default gateway from that specific machine or from the local LAN at all?

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to keep the connection up and running.

I used a script because I was connected remotely via `eth0` - shutting it down would have caused the connection to close.

The changes I made, in comparison to the script in my question, were 1st to ensure that the DHCP service is not running to prevent it from (re-)assigning an IP address to `eth0` and 2nd to *flush* `eth0` to remove the addresses.

```bsh
# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth="eth0"
eth_ip="192.168.178.20"
eth_netmask="255.255.255.0"
eth_broadcast="192.168.178.255"
eth_gateway="192.168.178.1"

for t in $tap; do
  openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

brctl addbr $br
brctl addif $br $eth

# Stop dhcpcd if running
systemctl stop dhcpcd

for t in $tap; do
  brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
  ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
done

#ip addr del $eth_ip dev $eth
ip addr flush dev $eth

ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast
route add default gw $eth_gateway $br


for t in $tap; do
  ifconfig $t up
done
ifconfig $br up
```

Comment: Basically it's the same thing in my answer, just that you kept all deprecated (if not obsoleted) `ifconfig`/`route`/`brctl`. Also there's no point in managing the the interface in a different manner. You can simply restart dhcpcd once the preparation is done. (Although it would be much better if you make it manage the bridge specifically, otherwise other interfaces might be getting IPs as well.)

Comment: Is `brctl` deprecated as well? Feel free to add/edit your answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Well at least in you case you don't need an extra program anyway. Whether bridge-utils is maintained? I don't really know (or care). I am not sure what more needs to be added to my answer to be honest. I think I have made everything pretty clear. (I stated that you need to stop **whatever manages the NIC**. To be fair, I couldn't even tell from your question what you were using.